# Using a REST Api, how to include "any kind of json" in my typed request model?

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, dynamic

I am using .NET Framework and ASP.NET Core to create a REST web Api.

This web api has a call that gets a request model to save data and some call that later retrieves the data.

Most of the data is structured information I need in the backend and it is saved into different fields and tables in the database. On retrieval it is loaded from those tables and returned.

This all works.

However, I now have a requirement where the caller wants to save and later retrieve  arbitrary data (lets just say a random json) as one of those fields. I can save and load json from the database that is not a problem, my problem is to build the web api model for my request.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([FromBody] ApiCallRequestModel request)
{
    // ...
}

public sealed class ApiCallRequestModel
{
    // structured, well known information
    public int? MaybeSomeNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SomeText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SubModel SomeData { get; set; }
    
    // one field of unknown json data
    public ??? CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

I could think of `dynamic` or maybe even `ExpandoObject` or `JObject` to try and I might, but I would like a solution that works because it's best practice, not just because I tried and it didn't fail today with my simple tests.

If everything else fails, I could just make the field a string and tell the client to put serialized json into it. But that's a workaround I would see as a last resort if this question yields no answers.

It has proven to be extremly hard to google this topic, since all words I would use lead me to pages explaining Json serialization of my request model itself. I know how that works and it's not a problem. The mix of structured data *and* free json is what I cannot find out from a somewhat authorative source.

So what type would you use here, **what is the best practice for receiving arbitrary json in one property of your model**?

Comment: Are you using Json.net? If so then you can use JToken as the type of that field.

Comment: You dont't specify your Core version, but given e.g. 3.1 and you're using system.text.json, `JsonElement` should work: https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/05/10/why-model-binding-to-jobject-from-a-request-doesnt-work-anymore-in-asp-net-core-3-1-and-whats-the-alternative/

Comment: I'm afraid the app is still .NET Framework, but I do use Json.Net

Comment: A `Dictionary` could be an elegant solution. Especially if the data is flat.

Comment: @RoarS. That is Microsofts Naming policy. It's horrible. Asp.Net-Core is the "Asp.Net" version named "Core", but does not use .NET Core, you can use .Net Framework with it. Sorry for the confusion, I wish Microsoft had a better naming policy.

Comment: If you want to be able to then after retrieve properties from that dynamic json object, then best option is to use dictionary, but then you would need to think about how would you retrieve it from the dictionary. What is the key? How will the consumer supply the key? Lower/upper case Scenarios? Maybe implementing `icomparable`. On top of that would all the values in the dictionary be of the same type? string? Object? Would you need to convert those?

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the data itself. I do not need to know what it is, I only need to supply it back to the client upon request.

Comment: Like @LasseV.Karlsen, my vote goes to `JToken`. Reason: It is simple, well-documented, and you're already using Json.NET.

Comment: I'll give JToken a try and see how it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to sum this up, as suggested I used a `JToken` from the `Json.NET` nuget package, since I already had that package in my project.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([FromBody] ApiCallRequestModel request)
{
    // ...
}

public sealed class ApiCallRequestModel
{
    // structured, well known information
    public int? MaybeSomeNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SomeText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SubModel SomeData { get; set; }
    
    // one field of unknown json data
    public JToken CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

Works like a charm.