# What is the difference between binding JsonDocument and a JsonElement in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-5.0, system.text.json

Task:
I am going to provide endpoint for 3rd party push notifications utilizing asp.net core 5.0.
Push notifications have different types and schemas. These notifications need to put in mysql database in json column, and read few values to create an internal event and put that in a queue. So I want to bind request body to a "json object" from which I can read values, and after that save in database as is.

Choice issue:
Asp.net core 5.0 uses `System.Text.Json`. `System.Text.Json` provides type `JsonDocument`, which according to documentation should to be disposed, and `JsonElement`. Binding mechanism allow to bind request body to both `JsonDocument` and `JsonElement`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessNotificationAsync(
    [FromBody] JsonDocument notification,
    [FromServices] IProcessNotificationCommand processCommand)
{
    await processCommand.ProcessAsync(notification);
    return NoContent();
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessNotificationAsync(
    [FromBody] JsonElement notification,
    [FromServices] IProcessNotificationCommand processCommand)
{
    await processCommand.ProcessAsync(notification);
    return NoContent();
}
```

Which approach is safe to use, bind to `JsonDocument` or bind to `JsonElement`?
If I use binding to JsonDocument would binding mechanism dispose JsonDocument, when request handled? Or it required to me to code that?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessNotificationAsync(
    [FromBody] JsonDocument notification,
    [FromServices] IProcessNotificationCommand processCommand)
{
    using (notification)
    {
        await processCommand.ProcessAsync(notification);
    }
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Not a direct duplicate because you want to use another json package, but if you have the choice, JToken from Json.NET [works well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497028/using-a-rest-api-how-to-include-any-kind-of-json-in-my-typed-request-model).

Comment: For `JsonDocument` if you want to read or manipulate you have to use the `RootElement` property which has the type of `JsonElement`. So using JsonDocument seems redundant to me. And if the framework allowing you to use the `JsonElement` you shouldn't be worried about the disposal of the parent document.

Comment: > And if the framework allowing you to use the JsonElement you shouldn't be worried about the disposal of the parent document             
@Eldar, Hope so, but want to be sure