# Create an IEnumerable<AbstractClass> of specific instances from different classes all inheriting from the abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, .net-core

I have controllers which, for the sake of backwards compatibility, only have one action. The JSON request comes with an attribute "type" which determines what the action should do with it.

My idea for a clean solution was to build a set of action handlers. They all inherit from an abstract class called ActionHandler which has two methods

```
public abstract bool CanHandle(ClientRequest request);
```

and

```
public abstract object Handle(dynamic request)
```

And it has a property

```
public abstract string ActionForController { get; }
```

in which the specific actionhandlers just return the name of the controller they want to handle for. This is not very important, but may help clarify something later.

The controller is inserted with an ActionHandlerRegister which has an IEnumerable and a method "GetActionHandler". It returns the first specific ActionHandler that can handle the request.

```
public ActionHandler GetActionHandler(ClientRequest request)
{
    foreach(var actionHandler in ActionHandlers)
    {
        if (actionHandler.CanHandle(request))
        {
            return actionHandler;
        }
    }

    throw new BadRequestException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, BadRequestExceptionTemplate, request.Type));
}
```

The controllers look like this:

```
public class LogController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IActionHandlerRegister<LogController> logHandlers;

    public LogController(IActionHandlerRegister<LogController> logHandlers)
    {
        this.logHandlers = logHandlers ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logHandlers));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic rawJson)
    {
        var jsonBody = ((JsonElement)rawJson).ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonBody))
        {
            return BadRequest(ActionHandler.BadRequestRequestNullOrTypeMissingError);
        }

        var clientRequest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClientRequest>(jsonBody);

        if (clientRequest == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientRequest.Type))
        {
            return BadRequest(ActionHandler.BadRequestRequestNullOrTypeMissingError);
        }

        try
        {
            var handler = logHandlers.GetActionHandler(clientRequest);
            var result = handler.Handle(rawJson);

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (BadRequestException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

For people paying attention: yes, I'm passing the rawjson to handler.Handle. This is because "ClientRequest" is something generic (from which I can read the type) but the handler needs the specific request, so it's deserializing again to something more specific. Maybe there are better solutions for that. Feel free to tell me.

In startup.cs, the insertion of the ActionHandlerRegister into the controller looks like this:

```
public void RegisterActionHandlersAsSingleton(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IEnumerable<ActionHandler> listOfActionHandlers =
        from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from actionHandlerType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
        where actionHandlerType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ActionHandler))
        select (ActionHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(actionHandlerType);

    services.AddSingleton<IActionHandlerRegister<LogController>>(new ActionHandlerRegister<LogController>(listOfActionHandlers.Where(a => a.ActionForController == nameof(LogController))));
    
    // other controllers ...
}
```

You might be able to guess, this last piece of code crashes at runtime telling me it's unable to cast to ActionHandler.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Object' to type
> 'TcServerModules.ActionHandlers.ActionHandler'.

I have been playing around with different solutions, but none of them scratch that itch. What would be a nice, true-to OO-design principle

Comment: You have two very obvious pieces of code where you use the `dynamic` type to lie to your compiler about what you really want to do or what you really expect. Since it will crash at runtime if your expectation is not met, using dynamic there really makes no sense. First step is stop lying to your own compiler. In my experience, code that is not syntactically sound is rarely written by people that build great concepts on top of it. Fix the code so it tells the compiler the truth, then think further.

Comment: Newtonsoft provides a way to serializing and deserializing types inheriting same abstract class, you can also write your own serializer and deserializer handlers

Comment: https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes

Comment: @nvoigt you're right, but the piece of information you are missing, which I thought wasn't relevant for the question, was that the incoming json is different for each request, except for the type attribute, which I'm basing my handler on. Maybe Jonas Høgh's idea can work. Thank you!

Comment: What I meant by lying is for example this line: "var jsonBody = ((JsonElement)rawJson).ToString();" Since your program will crash anyway if rawJson is anything but a JsonElement, you might as well make it a JsonElement instead of dynamic.

Comment: Instead of finding way to juggle your data from one hand to the other, you could just define a proper container that is fixed, that you can use as type, so you don't have to do all that manual deserializing and have that container have custom Json inside. See my question here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68497028/using-a-rest-api-how-to-include-any-kind-of-json-in-my-typed-request-model

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, I intend to. Furthermore, I think spzvtbg and Jonas' tips will alow me to actually just put the name of the abstract class of the clientrequest as parameter, which is even better (because it will allow me to just cast the request in my specific handler), but the problem of instantiating the handlers remains and is completely seperate.

Comment: @nvoigt Sure, like I said, I can improve that part. Still: only one route, one action, one method in my controller. What would be your solution to the problem I actually have?